# Insert a new record with a field containing total record in the table

Tags: sql

I wonder if it exists a function that allows me to get total rec count of a table to for new record insertion into the table?

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST" 
   (    "NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "ID" NUMBER,
  "FLAG" NUMBER
   )  ;
Insert into TEST (NAME,ID,FLAG) values ('Ahlahslfh',1,1);
Insert into TEST (NAME,ID, FLAG) values ('Buoiuop',2,1);
Insert into TEST (NAME,ID, FLAG) values ('UOIP',12,0);
```

[image]

My intention is to issue a statement that is equivalent to this:

```
INSERT INTO TEST(  NAME,  ID, FLAG )
  VALUES( 'TST', 3,1 );
```

The statement I used below generated error:

```
INSERT INTO TEST (  NAME,  ID, FLAG )
  VALUES ( 'TST', SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM TEST WHERE FLAG=1,1 );
```

Below is the final result I am expecting:

[image]

Is there a way around it? Of course, I can put them in a script, count the records into a variable and insert that variable into the field. I just wonder if there is more elegant solution and do this in 1 statement.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't do this... It's a really bad idea to store calculated values like that. Instead create a view that returns the table data plus that extra row.

Comment: Agreed. I should have called the field DisplayOrder not ID. Not sure ID came into my mind when I was mocking up the table for illustration purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely to be a very bad way to set an `id`.  In general, I think you should use sequences/identity/auto_increment and not worry about gaps.

But, you can do what you want using parentheses -- these are needed for subqueries:

```
INSERT INTO TEST(NAME, ID, FLAG)
    VALUES ('TST', 
            (SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM TEST WHERE FLAG = 1), 
            1 
           );
```

Or, alternatively:

```
INSERT INTO TEST(NAME, ID, FLAG)
    SELECT 'TST', COUNT(*) + 1, 1
     FROM TEST
     WHERE FLAG = 1;
```

I must emphasize that this seems dangerous.  It is quite possible that you will get duplicate `id`s.  You should really let the database insert a new value and not worry about gaps.

Comment: I know, it is not for ID, I put down ID for illustration only, not sure why ID came to my mind. It is misleading, I should have said it was display order not ID. My bad.